# How can I get powershell exception descriptions into a string?

Tags: exception, powershell

I want to have access to the same message that Powershell prints when you send an error record to the output stream

Example:

> This is the exception message At
> C:\Documents and
> Settings\BillBillington\Desktop\psTest\exThrower.ps1:1
> char:6
>
> - throw <<<<  (New-Object ArgumentException("This is the
>   exception"));
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [],
>     ArgumentException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : This is the exception

I when a get the last ErrorRecord by doing $Error[0] I can't seem to figure out how to get this information in a simple way

I found this 'Resolve-Error' function from the community extensions [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/resolve-error/) which does roughly what I want but it prints a huge semi-formatted list of stuff I don't need that I have to then strip

Is there way of accessing the message that Powershell uses or failing that a simpler way of getting hash of the values I care about so I can put them into a string in a format of my choosing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want a bit shorter message (more user friendly sometimes?) than @tomasr suggests this will do:

```
$error[0].ToString() + $error[0].InvocationInfo.PositionMessage
```

You will get something like:

```
Cannot find path 'C:\TEMP\_100804_135716\missing' because it does not exist.
At C:\TEMP\_100804_135716\test.ps1:5 char:15
+   Get-ChildItem <<<<  missing
```

This technical info will be excluded:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\TEMP\_100804_135716\missing:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Answer (score 24):

How about:

```
$x = ($error[0] | out-string)
```

Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 6):

I took it a bit further because I didn't like the multilines from $error[0].InvocationInfo.PositionMessage.

```
Function FriendlyErrorString ($thisError) {
    [string] $Return = $thisError.Exception
    $Return += "`r`n"
    $Return += "At line:" + $thisError.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
    $Return += " char:" + $thisError.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine
    $Return += " For: " + $thisError.InvocationInfo.Line
    Return $Return
}

[string] $ErrorString = FriendlyErrorString $Error[0]
$ErrorString
```

You can look at what else is availible to construct your own String via:

```
$Error | Get-Member
$Error[0].InvocationInfo | Get-Member
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Foreach ($Errors in $Error){
  #Log Eintrag wird zusammengesetzt und in errorlog.txt geschrieben
  "[$Date] $($Errors.CategoryInfo.Category) $($Errors.CategoryInfo.Activity) $($Errors.CategoryInfo.Reason) $($Errors.CategoryInfo.TargetName) $($Errors.CategoryInfo.TargetType) $($Errors.Exception.Message)" |Add-Content $Path\errorlog.txt -Encoding UTF8
}
```

You can also do this and you will get all Informations about the Error

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @tomasr, but shorter:

```
$($error[0])
```

For all errors in a script:

```
$($error)
```