# How to get line number with error inside trap in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I use trap to write errors to file, and want write line number where error ocured.

```
$_.Exception.StackTrace is not answer.
```

Where I can get line number of error? Maybe some predefined variable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can retrieve the line number from the `InvocationInfo` object on `$_`. For example, the script...

```
"Hello, World!"

function foo() {
  trap [Exception] {
    $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
    $_.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine
    continue;
  }

  [reflection.assembly]::loadfrom("C:\")
}

foo
```

... generates the output:

```
Hello, World!
10
34
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use `$_.InvocationInfo` properties, for example: `ScriptName`, `ScriptLineNumber`, `OffsetInLine`, `Line`.

For example to format position info in Visual Studio style:

```
trap {
    Write-Host "$($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptName)($($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)): $($_.InvocationInfo.Line)"
}
```

It will write something like:

```
C:\TEMP\test2.ps1(8): Get-Item missing
```

Also, you can just use `$_.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage`, see this post:
[How can I get powershell exception descriptions into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404642/how-can-i-get-powershell-exception-descriptions-into-a-string)

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to find an error line after the script has been executed, you can view `$Error` array. `$Error[0]` corresponds to the last error.

More details [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/05/12/powershell-error-handling-and-why-you-should-care/).