# Turn ExtendedTypeSystemException into string

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to turn an exception message into a string I can both `throw` and also write to the event manager, but having serious problems.

Have tried [How can I get powershell exception descriptions into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404642/how-can-i-get-powershell-exception-descriptions-into-a-string) this, but nothing on here works.

So this is what I use for validating credentials on a network:

```
$user = 'user'
$pass = 'pass'
$domain = "ldap://" + ( [ADSI]"" ).DistinguishedName

$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("$($env:USERDOMAIN)\$user", $(ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force))

New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ($domain, $user, $creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
```

If the credentials are valid you'll get something back like :

```
distinguishedName : {DC=COMP}
Path              : LDAP://COMP
```

If there's an error, it'll be something like:

```
format-default : The following exception occurred while retrieving member
"distinguishedName": "Unknown error (0x80005000)"
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], ExtendedTypeSystemException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

About the only thing I can do with that ouput, is drop the `format-default`.

Any suggestions on how to get just the top line?

So far I've tried `$PSItem`, `$_.ExceptionMessage`, `.ToString()`, `| Out-String`, `[string]`, on their own or as combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is a bit tricky, because it isn't thrown by `New-Object`, in fact, the object is created just fine. The error actually occurs at the point where PowerShell tries to display the object on the console and cannot find a property that the default display format for the object requires (in this case `DistinguishedName`). Hence it cannot be caught by putting the `New-Object` in a `try..catch` statement.

The error does appear in the automatic variable `$error` after it occurred, so you could check `$error[0]` for more information (e.g. use `$error[0].Message` to get just the error message), but you cannot suppress the error message without keeping the error from occurring in the first place (because it only occurs upon trying to display the object).

A better approach might be to capture the created object in a variable and then check for the presence of the property `DistinguishedName`.

```
$o = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ($domain, $user, $pass)
if ($o.DistinguishedName) {
    'Invalid credentials'
}
```

BTW, creating a secure string from a plaintext password and then decrypting that again because you need the password in plain text is quite pointless.

---

**Edit:**

I looked into this issue some more and if for some reason you must get the actual error message from PowerShell's default output formatting, you can do it like this:

```
$o = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ($domain, $user, $pass)

try {
    $o | Out-Default
} catch {
    $_.Exception.InnerException.Message
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't checking credentials, it's getting the error message to a string.
With regards to the EXAMPLE above - of course I wouldn't put a password in plain text, but if I did, it makes sense to decrypt the password back to make sure PSCredential took it. But again, just an example allowing others to copy n paste generating the error straight away.

In any case, I thank you for your input.  ````$error```` does give me what I want, but only if I don't assign ````New-Object```` to a variable, which I need to in order to check if they're valid. So close, yet so far.

Comment: Haven't had chance to test this yet but thank you for taking another look, I truly appreciate it. Will get chance on Monday morning